# Double slits experiment: how does the which-way entropy vary with the distance between slits and screen?

Tags: entropy, double-slit-experiment, density-operator

When the screen is just behind the slits we have perfect which way information. The entropy is log 2. It decreases if I place the screen in the Fresnel region (not to far). It decreases much more in the Fraunhofer region (great fresnel number) and information tends to zero when the distance L tends to infinity. I would like to know the forumula giving the which way entropy h(L,a,b,lambda)
where a is the width of the slit, b their distance, lambda the wave length of the particles (all are fixed parameters) and L the distance that varies in the different devices.
Is it correct to say that when in the device the screen is far from the slits, the particle is in a pure state and near them we have a mixture?
Thanks

Comment: for education, can you give a link on how "which-way entropy" is defined?

Comment: Look at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_relative_entropy#Definition
when the screen is very closed to the slits, its existence makes the particle’s density matrix
to be a 2 by 2 diagonal matrix with equal elements ½. So the associated entropy is log 2.
when it is far the density matrix is the |L+R><L+R| .

Comment: thanks ,because I could not find a link when searching for "which-way entropy"